# using python phonenumbers library to validate column of phone numbers

Tags: python, pandas, libphonenumber

I have a list of over 100k phone numbers in an excel sheet column. I've converted them all to strings and added a '+' in front of them. If there's a missing value in a row in the phone number column, I just added '+12345678901' in that row as a place holder. My column is called 'Phone'.

I've imported the phonenumbers (as 'pn') and pandas libraries. I'm trying to run various phonenumbers modules on the column, like parse, is_valid_number, is possible_number, etc., and put those outputs into new columns.

When I run the code on a single number in the column, it works fine. For example, all of the following works just fine:

```
num = pn.parse(data['Phone'][0])
print(num)
pn.is_valid_number(num)
pn.is_possible_number(num)
```

However, when I attempt any of this on the entire column, I always get some kind of error. I've been looking at the stack overflow solutions people have suggested for people with similar issues, but nothing seems to work for me. I'm sure I'm just making dumb mistakes/missing something, but I'd appreciate any and all help.

When I try the lambda function solution, it doesn't work. For example, the following results in the 'numbersparseexception: (1) The string supplied did not seem to be a phone number' error:

```
data['Parse Phone'] = data.apply(lambda x: pn.parse(x.Phone),axis=1)
```

Or if I try this, I get the same error. Or, if I apply the following to just a single row, I get the 'attributeerror: 'str' object has no attribute 'apply'' error, and I don't know why:

```
def parse(n):
    return pn.parse(n)
data['Phone'][0].apply(parse)
```

Again, I'm a novice, so I'm sure I'm just making a beginner's mistake here. But I would greatly appreciate any suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to their docs:

> The parse function will also fail completely (with a
> NumberParseException) on inputs that cannot be uniquely parsed, or
> that can't possibly be phone numbers.

If you are sure that your phone numbers are correct the problem may be that you didn't specify the second argument regarding the format.

> you also need to specify the country that the phone number is being dialled from (unless the number is in E.164 format, which is globally unique)

what you can try is to have a column that tells you whether the phone number is correct or not, something like:

```
data['Valid Phone'] = data.apply(lambda x: pn.is_valid_number(x.Phone),axis=1)
data['Phone Number']= data['Phone'].where(data['Valid Phone'], other=np.nan)
```

and then work with only this data

Comment: Thank you for this, I really appreciate your help. You know what, I am sure some of the phone numbers are not correct (I have some numbers that have way too many digits). I'll have to go back and put in some exceptions.